# Calling a sibling method throws 'Cannot read property 'X' of undefined'

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-event-emitter

I am super new to Angular and events in Angular.

My Parent Template:

```
    <child1 (myEvent)="child2.testMethod()"></child1>
    <child2 #child2 *ngIf="show"></child2>
```

I am getting 'Cannot read property 'testMothod' of undefined' error, but the 'testMethod' method gets called when *ngIf in the child2 component is removed.

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1c8hfj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known angular issue https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6179

Adding `@ViewChild('child2') child2;` to `AppComponent` solves it.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much!